# Could this post be hiding spam/advertising in plain sight?

Tags: discussion

Post in question: [How to replicate Excel's TEXTJOIN function in VBA UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763999/how-to-replicate-excels-textjoin-function-in-vba-udf)

At first glance, I wanted to report this post as spam, because it looks like it's trying to advertise their website. Additionally, the answer to the post showcases 4 results, which all look like generic spam/advertising to me - see the picture below:

[image: img1]

Would it be inappropriate to report this as spam?

Comment: there is a deleted question earlier from the answerer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754409/how-to-concatenate-cell-values-with-separator-in-excel-using-vbas-udf that has a remarkable similar wording as that question they answered. So if anything, it looks like some users team-up there.

Comment: @rene That was my suspicion - the "legitimate question" is really just a guise, and the two low reputation users are trying to beat the system.

Comment: I don't know- That _looks_ like a legit answer that just didn't have it's sample output encoded. Which could, of course, just be a very clever spam attempt. But now that it's been edited (by a mod) to add formatting to that section... It definitely looks a lot more like an answer now. I find this one... Borderline, definitely a big old grey area.

Comment: The post history of the asker indicates to me that they're escalating the light advertising they're doing in their posts.  (Many starting with "We are Freelensia, an online interpreter reservation platform located at freelensia.com.', followed by whatever moderately on-topic question that follows.)  Perhaps not outright spam, but certainly not wonderful behavior.

Comment: @rene Agreed. I had wondered when reading that. I was unsure whether to flag. dwirony - good on you for bringing here for discussion.

Comment: If the specific url is not important to the question or answer, changing it to example.com is an obvious solution.

Comment: It's so well done and yet so obvious that it's funny.

Comment: Hi dwirony, kendra ross qharr m69-snarky-and-unwelcoming Jasper-M my Q was downvoted and closed 2 years ago. Since then, others and I have edited to improve it. .
1. It is no longer using explicit website URLs in the post
2. The Q asks for a VBA solution that "allows array inputs". None of the other Qs that u guys mentioned asked for this, nor any other answers solve this additional challenge. The answer provided by user @lun inside my Q does solve it very elegantly.
I would like to request each of you to review your downvote and reverse it, if possible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Tricky this one and not clear cut.

It's been seen by two moderators (one of them being me) and both of us appear to have come down on the side of "not spam".

The question (and answer) look legitimate. The URLs are not actual links but text within the question and it appears the question is about processing a spreadsheet.

I disputed the latest spam flag which means that the flag had merit, but I didn't think that the question deserved deletion or the user getting the 100 point rep penalty. The question could have been edited to change the actual url to `http://www.example.com` and still preserved the meaning of the question.

That doesn't mean I won't change my mind if I see more of this sort of question in future.

Comment: I disputed the flag on the answer earlier. Do note that there is some correlation between the asker and answerer - but even so, the question seems to be OK when edited.

Comment: My personal opinion is that it is indeed spam. "Find interpreters online at domain.com" could be understood as a very SEO-friendly phrase.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Agreed. Especially given [the OP's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8074234/freelensia), which makes it clear that they represent the web site that their question (indirectly) promoted…

Comment: I'm in agreement with @Henrique de Sousa here - this Q&A looks like it's going out of its way to make text that would normally be considered spam in *any* context look like sample input. I can't bring myself to see this as a good-faith attempt on either user's part at making the Q&A relevant to the site, but rather a bad-faith attempt at *disguising* spam as a relevant Q&A.

Comment: Nothing wrong with editing the spam content out so as to disinfect the Q&A altogether (I personally am considering going so far as to redact it from all revisions when editing spam content out in future), but then you'd still have a potential behavioral problem to address - a separate matter, of course.

Comment: Given the number of times the company name appears in the users profile, it's hard to see this as anything but spam.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46630993) should probably also be cleaned up.

Comment: Re DavidG's comment: And in four languages!

Comment: @gre_gor - you have edit rights.

Answer (score 10):

If this is indeed not spam, both the asker and answerer should have no problem replacing those images and rewording their texts to remove any reference to the site.

Also, what are the odds that the asker has the name of the site that is being used in the answer?

In my perspective, you have to make a strong effort to not consider this as spam.

Comment: Indeed, and for that matter, they shouldn't even have had to *consider* making any references to their site *in the first place*, let alone replacing the strings after the fact. The fact that they did *at all* speaks for itself.

Comment: At this point, it's probably worth leaving alone, now that the spam's been edited out, but to watch the account.  If they do it again, then bring out the flamethrowers and cleanse it all.

Comment: @BoltClock The users reputation history is also a red flag, given they were serially upvoted not too long ago...

Comment: Hi Miguel, @Boltclock, DavidG my Q was downvoted and closed 2 years ago. Since then, others and I have edited to improve it. 1. It is no longer using explicit website URLs in the post 2. The Q asks for a VBA solution that "allows array inputs". None of the other Qs that u guys mentioned asked for this, nor any other answers solve this additional challenge. The answer provided by user lun inside my Q does solve it very elegantly. I would like to request each of you to review your downvote and reverse it, if possible. Thank you.